# useEffect throwing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs

I need this function to be called when setImage change the value so i put this inside a useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const tagsArray = tags.split(",").map((tag) => tag.trim().toLowerCase());

    // checar todos os valores
    if (!title || !image || !tags || !body) {
      console.log("title: ", title);
      console.log("image: ", image);
      console.log("tags: ", tags);
      console.log("body: ", body);
      setFormError("Por favor, preencha todos os campos");
    }
    if (formError) {
      return;
    }

    insertDocument({
      title,
      image,
      body,
      tagsArray,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdBy: user.displayName,
    });

    // redirect to home page
    navigate("/");
  }, [
    image,
    title,
    body,
    user.uid,
    user.displayName,
    insertDocument,
    navigate,
    tags,
    formError,
  ]);
```

It says "tags.split" isnt a function.
How can i fix that?

Comment: What is `tags`? We don't see the definition here.

Comment: My guess would be it expects a string, but that tags is is `undefined` here?

Comment: It occured because your `tags` is empty first check existing of it then create a map on it `tags && tags.map`